# Converting milliseconds since midnight to readable timestamp

Tags: db2

I have an application that logs the time an action occurred in milliseconds since midnight and stores it in a Db2 10.5 database table. I need to convert that figure to a human-readable timestamp output.

```
SELECT ACTION_NAME, 
ACTION_TIME
FROM ACT.ACTIONS

ALARM1 1818000
ALARM2 76500000
```

I want to be able to run a SELECT but have the value returned like

```
ALARM1 05:03
ALARM2 21:15
```

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the number of seconds to "midnight":

```
SELECT action_name, time '00:00' + (action_time/1000) second as action_time
FROM actions;
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=db2_11.1&fiddle=15506727e642682dadb0473eb0ca60b2) (based on DB2 11.1)

Comment: That works perfectly. Thanks also for the online example - that will save me a lot of time when trying things out.

Answer (score 0):

There is the [`TIME`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000858.html) type in Db2:

> The TIME function returns a time from a value.

so we could use that. 
We still need `DATE`, `TIME` or `TIMESTAMP` as the input, not `INT`. So let's try with TIMESTAMP. We can get the timestap of current day like this;

```
db2 "values timestamp(current date)"

1                  
-------------------
2019-08-23-00.00.00

  1 record(s) selected.
```

Now we can simply add the offset in either seconds or microseconds. E.g. with 76500000:

```
db2 "values timestamp(current date) + (76500000/1000) seconds"

1                  
-------------------
2019-08-23-21.15.00

  1 record(s) selected.
```

and with time:

```
db2 "values time(timestamp(current date) + (76500000/1000) seconds)"

1       
--------
21:15:00
```

With our data:

```
db2 "create table ACT.ACTIONS(action_name varchar(10), action_time int)"
db2 "insert into ACT.ACTIONS values ('ALARM1',1818000)"
db2 "insert into ACT.ACTIONS values ('ALARM2',76500000)"
db2 "select action_name, time( timestamp(current date) + (action_time/1000) seconds) as time from act.actions"

ACTION_NAME TIME    
----------- --------
ALARM1      00:30:18
ALARM2      21:15:00

  2 record(s) selected.
```

(note that you likely have an error in your example)

Edit:
As noted, there is no need for CURRENT TIMESTAMP, I didn't notice that we can use STRING representation of the time, i.e. '00:00' as @a_horse_with_no_name shown:

```
db2 "select action_name, time('00:00')  + (action_time/1000) seconds as action_time_fmt from act.actions"

ACTION_NAME ACTION_TIME_FMT
----------- ---------------
ALARM1      00:30:18       
ALARM2      21:15:00       

  2 record(s) selected.
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need the milli-second part, you can do e.g.

```
values timestamp('0001-01-01') + (1818005 / 1000) seconds + (mod(1818005,1000)*1000) microseconds"

1                         
--------------------------
0001-01-01-00.30.18.005000

1 record(s) selected.
```